# postgres standby - what not WAL records can be replayed?

Tags: postgresql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/standby-settings.html

> The delay occurs only on WAL records for transaction commits. Other
>   records are replayed as quickly as possible, which is not a problem
>   because MVCC visibility rules ensure their effects are not visible
>   until the corresponding commit record is applied.

I thought while streaming replication xlog is replayed on slave. Local transactions are not replayed. Remote statements that skip WAL (Eg `create table nologging`) are not replayed on slave. Now I'm confused - **what are those other records that are replayed not waiting for `recovery_min_apply_delay`**?..

Comment: The pass you quoted tells exactly this: 'transaction commits'.  So the changes that are made are replayed, but not the commit - effectively meaning that the changed data is already sitting there waiting to go 'live' when the commit itself is replayed.

Comment: Ah! I thought it was my bad English - the the WAL is replayed, not committing transactions from it until `recovery_min_apply_delay` expires for that transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of transaction log records other than commits.

Transaction ID allocations (roughly like a BEGIN delayed until first actual write). Inserts, updates, deletes, vacuum, lots of internal operations.

Synchronous streaming replication  *only* waits for confirmation that the replica has replayed *commit* transaction log records. Not any of the others.

Some things, like the `UNLOGGED` tables you refer to, do not generate any transaction logs at all. So they cannot affect replicas. But that is not what that passage in the docs is talking about.

Comment: yes- thank you. @dezso already explained that to me. My bad English is the reason to misunderstand docs. If it would say `The delay on WAL records occurs only for transaction commits` instead - I would not ask silly questions.